# Measured doppler shift error biggest on direct flight on target

Tags: rf, frequency, radar

Following scenario:
There is a radar on a plane which emits a CW Signal and outputs the measured doppler shifts from the reflection of a static target.

I can see from the data, that the error of the doppler shift (error to theoretical doppler shift) is biggest when the plane flies directly onto the target (or away from it).

Is this normal?

Comment: Do you actually know the principle of doppler radar, or what's the doppler effect?

Comment: Yes, I do think that I know the principle of the doppler effect. At least the basics. I know that the doppler shift is greatest at direct flight onto the target. But why should the **error** be bigger (again, compared to the theoretical value)

Comment: Is the error some spread in measured position, to which you've attempted a straight-line fit?